# Magento default cart quantity 1 product not 0

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

Acording to the screenshot http://prntscr.com/507h9f the default quantity of the shopping cart it is 0. How can i set it up as 1? Thanks

Comment: In which scenario would you have to set to 1? I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: sorry? i don't understand

Comment: I mean, if the basket is 0 it normally means nothing is in the basket hence the value 0. How come you are setting it to 1 as default?

Answer (score 10):

Try the following steps,

1. Go to `Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Inventory-> Product Stock Options` from the Menu.
2. Click on Add Minimum Qty button (next to Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart option).
3. Choose Customer Group: ALL GROUPS as you want this to be applied to all users.
4. Enter 1 for Minimum Qty.
5. Save Config.